# JLayeredPane not painting low component if both components are same size and full screen

Tags: java, swing

`JLayeredPane` not painting low component if both components are same size and full screen

How software works:

JFrame <- APanel <- JLayeredPane <- (Layered subcomponents)

- My software is full screen software.
- APanel is BorderLayout component.
- JLayeredPane is BorderLayout.CENTER in APanel

```java
Panel1 gp = new Panel1(); //Panel1 extends JPanel
gp.setSize(jlp.getSize());
jlp.add(gp);
gp.initializeDisplay(); //starts repaint() loop
jlp.setLayer(gp, 90);

Panel2 lp = new Panel2(); //Panel2 extends JPanel
lp.setSize(jlp.getSize());
lp.initializeDisplay();  //starts repaint() loop
lp.initializeComponents(); //Adds and moves components
jlp.add(lp);
jlp.setLayer(lp, 110);
```

When I make like this, only `Panel2` is displayed. `Panel1`'s `paintComponent()` looks like this (Just draw image):

```
g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

`Panel2` contains a lot of buttons and labels.
This method fixes the problem.

```
Panel1 gp = new Panel1();
gp.setSize(jlp.getSize());
jlp.add(gp);
gp.initializeDisplay();
jlp.setLayer(gp, 90);

Panel2 lp = new Panel2();
lp.setSize(jlp.getWidth() - 1, jlp.getHeight() - 1); //Changed here
lp.initializeDisplay();
lp.initializeComponents();
jlp.add(lp);
jlp.setLayer(lp, 110);
```

But this method causes problem again:

```
Dimension cs = new Dimension(jlp.getWidth() - 1, jlp.getHeight() - 1);
GrassPane gp = new GrassPane();
gp.setSize(cs);
jlp.add(gp);
gp.initializeDisplay();
jlp.setLayer(gp, 90);

LobbyPane lp = new LobbyPane(this);
lp.setSize(cs);
lp.initializeDisplay();
lp.initializeComponents();
jlp.add(lp);
jlp.setLayer(lp, 110);
```

Please add a comment if you need some more info such as codes.

Comment: Are you calling the super's paintComponent method in your override? Is the top JPanel non-opaque? Is your "repaint() loop" Swing thread-safe? A [mcve] would be much help here.

Comment: I can confirm that if components have same bounds (location, size) and are opaque, the lower ones `paintComponent()` is not called. Probably also true if no part of the lower one is *obviously* visible. I suspect this is not just the JLayeredPane... [mcve] is just 20 lines of code...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger well, when components are opaque, it is intentional that completely obscured components are not painted. Interestingly, even transparent components have repainting problems with `JLayeredPane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an opaque component overlaps another, it is intentional to skip painting completely obscured components. This can only become a problem, when component wrongly declared to be opaque. So when you implement your own components painting a transparent image, they should implement the `isOpaque()` method returning `false`.

Interestingly, I still could reproduce a repainting problem with transparent components using the following code:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
JLayeredPane pane = f.getLayeredPane();
JButton b = new JButton("Normal Text");
b.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
b.setBounds(20, 20, 300, 100);
JLabel l = new JLabel("Overlay");
l.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
l.setBounds(20, 20, 300, 100);
l.setOpaque(false);
pane.add(l);
pane.add(b);
f.setSize(350, 200);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Here, the text “Overlay” may or may not appear initially, but as soon as one of the button’s properties change (e.g. receiving the focus or getting clicked), the text will disappear.

The problem lies in the following property:

```
System.out.println(pane.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled());
```

will print `true`. And “optimized drawing” means that some of the children might not get rendered in certain situations. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()) says:

> Returns true if this component tiles its children -- that is, if it can guarantee that the children will not overlap.

Of course, `JLayeredPane` will never tile the children, but stack them on top of each other and can never guaranty that they won’t overlap. Still, for some reason, the Swing developers decided to implement the following logic:

```
private void validateOptimizedDrawing() {
    boolean layeredComponentFound = false;
    synchronized(getTreeLock()) {
        Integer layer;

        for (Component c : getComponents()) {
            layer = null;

            if(SunToolkit.isInstanceOf(c, "javax.swing.JInternalFrame") ||
                   (c instanceof JComponent &&
                    (layer = (Integer)((JComponent)c).
                                 getClientProperty(LAYER_PROPERTY)) != null))
            {
                if(layer != null && layer.equals(FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER))
                    continue;
                layeredComponentFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(layeredComponentFound)
        optimizedDrawingPossible = false;
    else
        optimizedDrawingPossible = true;
}
```

So whenever the components are not `JComponent` instances or don’t have the `LAYER_PROPERTY` property, which is always the case when using the default layer like the above example, the pane decides that optimized paint was possible, despite nothing in the actual layout logic changed.

So when we change

```
pane.add(l);
pane.add(b);
```

to

```
Object myLayer = JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER+1;
pane.add(l, myLayer);
pane.add(b, myLayer);
```

the problem will disappear, as `System.out.println(pane.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled());` will print `false` now.

Beware of the autoboxing. When you are using `pane.add(l, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER+1);` or just `pane.add(l, 1);`, it would call `add(Component comp, int index)` instead of the desired `add(Component comp, Object constraints)`.

Comment: Thank u very much! I usually removed super.paintComponent(); so i didn't think about that. I fixed it by calling setOpaque(false); in constructor. Your answer was very helpful!